# Removing nodes from Firebase best practices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a firebase project where i have 2 android apps connected to the same Database, let's say the first app is an "user app" which i'm distributing to some friends and the second one is the "admin app"(an app that is only on my personal phone). The "user app" basically just displays some infos about events in my city, while i use the "admin app" to add/delete those events from the database

In my user app i have a pretty standard RecyclerView displaying some cards using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Clicking on a card leads to a new Activity which displays more info about the event, using an Intent i pass an Id as a String  which loads the corrisponding node in the database  and everything works just fine. The problem is that when i delete a node (from Firebase console or from amy "admin" app) sometimes the "card" in my recyclerview is still avaible and clicking on it leads to a NullPointerExeption because the object i'm looking for is obviously no longer in the database.

I'm using .keepSynced(true) on my DatabaseReference and i've set setPersistanceEnabled and i think this might be the problem.

my Adapter declaration @OnStart looks like this :

```
if(recyclerView.getAdapter == null){         
eventAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DynamicData,EventViewHolder>
           (
            DynamicData.class,
            R.layout.event_card,
            EventViewHolder.class,
            eventRef.orderByChild("eName")
            ){

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(EventViewHolder viewHolder, DynamicData model, int position) {
            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setId(post_key);
            viewHolder.setName(model.geteName());
            viewHolder.setTime(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent toEvent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditEvent.class);
                    toEvent.putExtra("EVENT_ID",post_key);
                    startActivity(toEvent);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

   recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
   if(rcState != null){
     recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(rcState);
   }
```

so nothing really strange is going on here.

My OnSavedInstanceState :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT, linearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState());
    rcState = outState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT);
}
```

The if(recyclerView.getAdapter() == null) clause that i use OnStart togheter with the code in OnSavedInstanceState is the only thing that makes my recycler view scroll to the right position. Without this code whenever i change activiy with the Intent (by clicking on a recyclerView Item) and then come back the recyclerview gets recreated and it starts once again from top

**Important** : right now i'm calling

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    eventAdapter.cleanup();
}
```

rather than onStop() since it's apparently the only way i can keep my recyclerView position when switching activity.

In my "admin app" when i want to delete some event from the db i use this code :

```
 //Query fetching events older than 6 hours
       Query returnsixHoursOldEvents = 
     eventRef.orderByChild("date").endAt(six_hours_cutoff);
    returnsixHoursOldEvents.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();



            }
        }
```

now the problem is that since i'm deleting this events from my "admin app" i can't notify the adapter on my "user app". What happens is that sometimes (seems to happen randomly) if a friend of mine opens his app he can still see the events i just delete in his recyclerview, but if he clicks on it the app crashes since the Node in the database is no longer avaible

is keepSynced or setPersistanceEnabled the problem ? any work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shared data model it is quite possible that one user deleted data that another user still sees, especially when one of them is not connected to Firebase for a while. Your code will have to handle that situation.

Methods like `removeValue()` are immune to whether the data exists or not: they just ensure that after they've execute, the data is gone.

Comment: Yeah i thought about simply handling "user app" side directly... the simpliest solution would be to check if the event still exist OnClick and only then exectuing the intent to start the new activity, otherwise remove it from the adapter but i was wondering if there was some other workaround i wasn't aware about ! thanks for your answer Frank ! and thanks for Firebase of course

Comment: a friend of mine is visualizing data that i deleted over 5 days ago and he doesn't visualize the new data i added today.(Once again it happens randomly, everything works fine on most phones). It looks like his adapter never changes and i think it might be caused by a "trick" i used to save the recyclerview scroll position, i edited my post with more details